# Where is the "Blazor WebAssembly Standalone App" template?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I've recently installed Visual Studio 17.8.0 Preview 5.0 on my Windows 11 machine and I'm trying to follow a tutorial (and the official info) that says that there're two new templates for Blazor in .NET 8 RC2.

The first one is called simply "Blazor Web App" and is the most generic one, but there should be another one, called "Blazor WebAssembly Standalone App" that doesn't appear among the options I have for choosing when I create a new project...

I've tryed repairing VS installation. I've also tried a full uninstall and reinstall but no luck...

I have the latest compilation of the Spanish SDK also: dotnet-sdk-8.0.100-rc.2.23502.2-win-x64

So "dotnet new --version" shows 8.0.100-rc.2.23502.2

Doing "dotnet new list blazor" shows:

```html
Nombre de la plantilla               Nombre corto        Idioma  Etiquetas
-----------------------------------  ------------------  ------  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
Aplicación .NET MAUI Blazor          maui-blazor         [C#]    MAUI/Android/iOS/macOS/Mac Catalyst/Windows/Tizen/Blazor/Blazor Hybrid
Aplicación Blazor para WebAssembly   blazorwasm          [C#]    Web/Blazor/WebAssembly/PWA
Aplicación Blazor WebAssembly vacía  blazorwasm-empty    [C#]    Web/Blazor/WebAssembly/PWA/Empty
Aplicación Blazor Server             blazorserver        [C#]    Web/Blazor
Aplicación Blazor Server vacía       blazorserver-empty  [C#]    Web/Blazor/Empty
Blazor Web App                       blazor              [C#]    Web/Blazor/WebAssembly
```

The "blazorwasm" template that appears in the list generates the .NET 7 project structure, so is not the new "Standalone App" template.

Is there any way that I could install the "Blazor WebAssembly Standalone App" template individually for using it?

Comment: I mean, choosing blazor wsam without choosing asp.net core hosted, then it's the standalone app. And for .net 8, `When an app is created that exclusively runs on the Blazor WebAssembly hosting model without server-side rendering and interactivity, the app is called a standalone Blazor WebAssembly app`

Answer (score 0):

We have [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-8.0#blazor-webassembly) here:

> Blazor web apps can use the Blazor WebAssembly hosting model to enable
> client-side interactivity. When an app is created that exclusively
> runs on the Blazor WebAssembly hosting model without server-side
> rendering and interactivity, the app is called a standalone Blazor
> WebAssembly app.

For .net version before 8, like .net 7, we have option for

[image]

For .net 8 we have, and here's [a blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-dotnet-8-preview-6/) to describe the template:

> The Blazor Web App template now provides an option in Visual Studio
> for enabling interactivity using the server render mode:

and

> In this preview release we’ve removed the Blazor Server template and
> the “ASP.NET Core hosted” option from the Blazor WebAssembly template

[image]